# Geometric Interval Classification with GEE JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reclassify

I am attempting to perform a geometric interval classification using the Google Earth Engine JavaScript API. I have some code that calculates the geometric intervals given a start/end value & number of classes. Below is my code snippet...

```
// Define parameters
var numClasses = 30
var minValue = 1
var maxValue = 3000 

// Generate geometric intervals
var intervals = ee.List.sequence(1, numClasses).map(function(i) {
  var minInterval = minValue * Math.pow((maxValue / minValue), i / numClasses);
  var maxInterval = minValue * Math.pow((maxValue / minValue), (i + 1) / numClasses);
  return [minInterval, maxInterval]
});

// Print intervals (returns NULL values)
print(intervals);

// Example execution outside of the map function
print(minValue * Math.pow((maxValue / minValue), 2 / numClasses))
```

The code itself seems to work when I print an individual result to the console, however my `.map()` function to generate the intervals is returning null values. Any idea what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're mixing Java script with GEE methods. By using only GEE methods, you can rewrite your code as:

```
// Define parameters
var numClasses = 30;
var minValue = 1;
var maxValue = 3000; 

// Generate geometric intervals
var intervals = ee.List.sequence(1, numClasses).map(function(i) {
  //var minInterval = minValue * Math.pow((maxValue / minValue), i / numClasses);
  var minInterval = ee.Number.expression('minValue*(maxValue/minValue)**(i/numClasses)',
                                         {'minValue': minValue,
                                          'maxValue': maxValue,
                                          'i': i,
                                          'numClasses': numClasses
                                         });
                                         
  //var maxInterval = minValue * Math.pow((maxValue / minValue), (i + 1) / numClasses);
  var maxInterval = ee.Number.expression('minValue*(maxValue/minValue)**((i+1)/numClasses)',
                                         {'minValue': minValue,
                                          'maxValue': maxValue,
                                          'i': i,
                                          'numClasses': numClasses
                                         });

  
  return [minInterval, maxInterval];

});

// Print intervals (returns NULL values)
print(intervals);

// Example execution outside of the map function
print(minValue * Math.pow((maxValue / minValue), 2 / numClasses))
```

Running [above code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/92aeb6be72729c16b2e490af7f7fe4be) at GEE code editor, it produces following result without any null values:

[image]